# Giving a users without access to a document library access to a Docset

Tags: permissions, document-set

I want to give a couple of users who don't have access to a document library, access to the whole of a document set in that library including its welcome page. Doesn't seem an easy task as the welcome page lives in the hidden forms subfolder of the document library. I would have to give these users read access to the whole library which I don't want?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other solution other than giving read permission to the root of the Library and then uniquely securing items in the Library so those users will only see Document Set.

Below is another Solution you can try out - I hope it should work.

Document Set is a kind of Folder. So idea is - Using SharePoint Designer open out-of-the box Welcome Page, Copy its content and create a new Page in Pages Library (Assuming the users has permission to this library).

Now using PowerShell - Get Folder (Document Set) and Set WelcomePage to the new Page that you created above.

Comment: Thanks Amal, that's the problem in trying to avoid which is users outside of the Teamsite membership being able to read (and search) for documents in the root of the Doclib they are not supposed to (and of a sensitive nature).